# Jquery sortable using up-down arrow on dynamic div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am generating `div` boxes using script :

```
$('.FieldContainer a.add').click(function(){
   $('.FieldContainer').append(
      '<div class="OrderingField">'+
      '<div class="LeftFloat">'+
      'Item'+
      '</div>'+
      '<div class="RightFloat Commands">'+
      '<button value="up" >Up</button>'+
      '<button value="down" >Down</button>'+
      '</div>'+
      '</div>'
   );
});
```

Here is my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/maziar/P2XDc/ link

Up-Down button are working on preloaded `div` elements but div element which are generating using above script are not moving up-down using that button .

How to correct this?

Edit:

Working Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/P2XDc/182/

Comment: can you explain what is not working?? please

Comment: Did you try calling moveUp & moveDown after you append the controls?

Comment: Immediate thought is that the function isn't being attached to the object(s). Have you pursued that possibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.FieldContainer a.add').click(function(){

    $('.FieldContainer').append(

    '<div class="OrderingField">'+
    '<div class="LeftFloat">'+
    'Item'+
    '</div>'+
    '<div class="RightFloat Commands">'+
    '<button value="up" >Up</button>'+
    '<button value="down" >Down</button>'+
    '</div>'+
    '</div>');

    $(".FieldContainer").sortable("destroy");
    $(".FieldContainer").sortable({
        items: ".OrderingField",
        distance: 10
    });

});
```

Comment: @EmptyData this is so so simple , you have to do this because when `sortable` is begin defined at first time new `div`s are not exists , so you have to `destroy` it an again define it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply the `.click()` you peform on startup also on newly created divs, as the jQuery selector is currently only executed on startup. You might perform this like the following:

```
$('.FieldContainer a.add').click(function(){
    $('.FieldContainer').append(
        '<div class="OrderingField">'+
        '<div class="LeftFloat">'+
        'Item'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div class="RightFloat Commands">'+
        '<button value="up" >Up</button>'+
        '<button value="down" >Down</button>'+
        '</div>'+
        '</div>'
    ).find('button').click(function() { 
        var btn = $(this);
        var val = btn.val();
        if (val == 'up')
            moveUp(btn.parents('.OrderingField'));
        else
            moveDown(btn.parents('.OrderingField'));
    });
});
```

UPDATE: as your `click()` needs to be applied to buttons instead, I inserted the `find('button')` selector. I updated [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P2XDc/183/).

Comment: @EmptyData I updated my answer to work properly. including a working fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Add a global handler for all buttons:

```
$(".FieldContainer").on("click", "button", function(){console.log("works")})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the elements after the events have already been bound. If you want to have the same events on dynamically added elements, you will need to bind the click to those buttons after they are added